# Error: serial port 'com0' isn’t found. While installing arch Linux on dual boo

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot

I had previously installed vanilla arch by following a tutorial using archinstall script, I did encounter some issues with network manager but all were resolved.
The problem I has then was with installing dotfiles over a minimal profile, which didn’t go as expected and I had no option to format. But then couldn’t find anything to format the dual boot thing.
So I tried to reinstall using the flash drive which again didn’t work.

Later I format the drive from windows and used balena etcher to flash arch on my pendrive thinkin rufus might be the issue which is dumb of me
This again didn’t work but then got some new error, I’m not sure if a video of large size could be uploaded here directly so will be sharing a link to that
**serial port com0 not found**
https://jmp.sh/zXjwm2o8

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a valid startup of an Arch ISO image.

The very briefly visible `error: serial port 'com0' isn't found.` just before GRUB appears is from either the system firmware or (most likely) GRUB. In both cases, it would be related to "headless" server setups - i.e. systems that have no GPU or normal display at all, just a serial port for console access.

The GRUB on your boot media seems to be configured to look for a serial port, to perhaps use it as an alternative "display" if the normal display is not available for some reason. But maybe your system does not have any classic RS-232-style serial ports?

In a nutshell: **it is harmless.** Feel free to ignore it and proceed with the (re)installation of Arch.